# Error while installing IIS on VM?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, remote-desktop, iis

My Client has set up a VM for me. It is a Windows-7,64 bit machine. 
When I tried to configure IIS on that machine , It is showing an error,
`An error has occurred.Not all the features were successfully changed`. I have gone through several forums , updated .NET framework to 4.5 but still the same result.

After that When I checked my permission on the remote machine, I was added as a member of `Remote Desktop Users` group .

So is this the reason for getting this kind of error?

Only administrators can use `Turn Windows Features on or off` to configure IIS?

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip it and upload the zip (Cloud hoster) and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an Administrator of that VM. Refer [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7) for more..